# Why is $\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}(j+i-k) = \sum_{k=1}^{i}(k)$

Tags: summation, arithmetic

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}(j+i-k) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{i}(k)$

I know the above are equal through testing it out with arbitrary values, but I can't get an intuitive grasp as to why this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=j}^{i+j} (i+j-k) \\
&= (i) + (i-1) + \cdots + ((i+j)-(i+j-1)) + ((i+j)-(i+j)) \\
&= (i) + (i-1) + \cdots + 1 + 0 \\
&= 0 + 1 + \cdots + (i-1) + i \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{i} k.
\end{align}
Also 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{m} n = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=j}^{i+j} (i+j-k) = \sum_{k=1}^{i} k = \binom{i+1}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, so thank you for the quick answer. Is this more of an identity that people can recognize quickly, or is this a less commonly encountered but easily solvable conversion? I'm an undergrad with up to Calc 3, but have never seen this type of problem before.

Comment: @Mike The first part is writing the summation in reverse order. The second part is, after some practice, an identity. The $\binom{n}{m}$ term is the binomial coefficient, which was used for a "nice" looking result.

Answer (score 3):

Write out the terms in the first sum:
$$\sum_{k=j}^{i+j} (j+i-k)=i+(i-1)+\cdots + 1 + 0 = \sum_{k=1}^i k$$